# Heroku Block Requests to URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, heroku, system-administration

For some reason, a script of some sort makes a repeated request to my site every second or faster to a URL that doesn't exist. It's painful because it clogs up the logs (and is an unnecessary (although small) consumption of resources). Just wondering if there's a good way to deal with this for a site hosted on Heroku. The requests come from a different IP address each time.

Edit: As a note, the requests are always to the exact same URL.

Here's an example, which repeats every second or so, except from a different IP:

```
Feb 22 08:37:28 myApp app/web.1: ActionController::RoutingError (Not Found):
Feb 22 08:37:28 myApp app/web.1:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:31:in `not_found'
Feb 22 08:37:28 myApp app/web.1:   app/controllers/my_controller.rb:141:in `my_method'
Feb 22 08:37:28 myApp app/web.1: [Exceptiontrap] Raised Exceptiontrap::Rack::Exception
Feb 22 08:37:28 myApp app/web.1: [Exceptiontrap] Catched Exception: ActionController::RoutingError
Feb 22 08:37:28 myApp app/web.1: Started GET "/aSpecificURL" for 109.242.56.44 at 2014-02-22 13:37:28 +0000
Feb 22 08:37:28 myApp heroku/router: at=info method=GET path=/aSpecificURL host=www.myApp.com request_id=9caeabcf-adcc-417f-940d-0458a81d9c32 fwd="109.242.56.44" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=24ms status=404 bytes=1632
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't block specific requests through heroku. It sounds to me like someone is scanning your app for security vulnerabilities.

You could setup [cloudflare](http://cloudflare.com) to help block some of the requests. But overall, this is pretty common and not something to worry about.